# Blender screen won't refresh. Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation

I recently got a windows 10 laptop. I've brought all my blend projects into this computer and installed blender. But whenever I boot blender up the screen will stay frozen on whatever frame it was left on unless I switch to another app and come back. As you might imagine this makes it impossible to work in. I've had this happen with one other program (sonic 2 hd) and I can't figure out how to make it work, I've uninstalled and reinstalled blender several times, I've tried the zip and nothing works

Comment: If you are having this issue with other programs it means it is not an issue with blender, but with how your hardware/OS is configured. Usually graphic issues are related to the drivers for the GPU (graphics card). Try updating to the latest version.

Comment: ive only had this problem with one other program (see question) and upgrade what to the latest version?

Comment: Drivers for the GPU

Comment: tried it, did nothing. i even reinstalled the driver and it still didnt work

Comment: I tried doing a little research on programs freezing on Windows 10, and was overwhelmed... Out of curiosity, if you launch Blender from cmd, does it print anything interesting when this happens? That may help us narrow it down.

The only thing I can think of that your two listed programs have in common is that they both use SDL 2.0. You might try another program that uses it for window rendering and see if you have the same problem; if you do, it might involve SDL windowing. I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your response, youve been the most helpful so far. I cant find anything about SDL, but I tried running blender from the CMD and it didnt print out anything. I ended up just returning the computer.